# Do Karate UI support Angular UI based application testing

Tags: karate

If karate supports Angular testing, can i have some example so that i can look into it.

Have been going through locators given at https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/#locators but unable to get exact information on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need, Karate works with plain HTML.

And if you need to do some specifc JS helpers (which is all that frameworks that claim to support Angular do), just use the tips here and make re-usable functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

If you still have a question, ask a new question and provide a sample (can be online, see examples in link above) for us to understand and discuss.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply, will bring more samples for discussion. BTW Great Framework and really appreciate it!

Comment: @SandeepPadala also see this example for an angular app: https://gist.github.com/ptrthomas/ac04f3501f608534f588d4e539b804c5

Comment: this is great, after going through few syntax's practically seems like this framework can handle everything. Thank you!! Will definitely bring up more question on the go!