# Karate-UI Press two keys at once

Tags: automation, karate

I am stuck at a step where i need to press two keys at once in karate ui

```
And input('.myclass',  [Key.F2 , Key.ENTER])
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Currently not supported. You should be able to work around by submitting key events via JavaScript. See here for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: Thanks peter. I will try this