# Dropdown selected but value not retained after refresh in karate

Tags: ui-automation, karate

While selecting the dropdown values, select method works with all input parameters like options, values and index. But when I try to validate it, the default selected value is diaplayed instead of the selected one.

I tried getting help from the below question but still the things are same.

[Karate UI: Selected option not applied on next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222852/karate-ui-selected-option-not-applied-on-next-page)

For me the values are present in select tag only and i troed writing specific locator for the value and clicking it.. Still it's not taling up the updated values. Any other method which we can use or any other way of implementing it will be helpful.

Comment: sorry can't help you without ANY info. follow this process (if you can): https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Hi Peter, same thing is happening in my case also. Like in a web form to update user data where input and dropdown options will be there. Data entered in textbox with <input> are saving when user click on save. In case of <textarea> and dropdown <select> changed values are not showing in the UI after save. the webform developed in React JS.

Comment: @PeterThomas mouse().move('locator').submit() worked for me in this case.. But its taking much time considerably, 30 seconds at each dropdown would prove costly. Select was not working so I tried combination of mouse().move('locator').submit() and input(), any way I can reduce the time taken by these operations?

Comment: this is an area I expect you to have some respect for the developers of the framework, provide more data, contribute and make karate better, does that make sense ? every web app is different. there can be all kinds of JS involved that you CANNOT explain by questions like these. it is up to you how you want to proceed.

Comment: Appreciate the efforts! Thanks