# Karate UI - When i enter expiration date, it is not taking it correctly

Tags: karate

I want to enter month and year in the expiration date field. and I used this `And input('#card_expDate', "0828")`

But it takes the value in the field as `82/80`.. I want it to take it as `08/28`

Tried `And input('#card_expDate', "08/28")` as well and no luck

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this, most likely because the page has some fancy javascript. No one can help you unless they see the actual page.

The only suggestions I have are:

- try adding a delay before each keystroke: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#input

  - e.g. `* input('#card_expDate', '0828', 100)`
- try setting the value using `value()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#valueset

  - e.g. `* value('#card_expDate', '08/28')`
- resort to executing custom JS in the page to do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I used this 
And scroll('#card_expDate').input('script("0+8+2+8")') and it worked