# Need help on Drag and Drop of web element using Karate framework

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I am working on one of the UI automation project with Karate framework.
I have a scenario, where user needs to drag an element and drop it on to canvas.

Attached the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFIbF.png)
The karate doc doesn't give more information on dragging element and dropping it.
Could you please help us ?

Comment: drag and drop IS hard. if this link doesn't help, you have to do some research or contribute code, or look for another framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: I tried the same code given in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637144/karate-ui-drag-and-drop/60800181#60800181" , code execution is passing but actually element is no dragging as expected.

Comment: And retry(30).highlight('.inline-block')
    * delay(4000)
    * script("var myDragEvent = new Event('dragstart'); myDragEvent.dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()")
    * waitFor('.inline-block').script("_.dispatchEvent(myDragEvent)")
    * script("var myDropEvent = new Event('drop'); myDropEvent.dataTransfer = myDragEvent.dataTransfer")
    * script('#canvasContainer > div.drag-activity-section.compass-icon', "_.dispatchEvent(myDropEvent)")
    And retry(30).highlight("#canvasContainer > div.drag-activity-section.compass-icon")
    * delay(4000)

Comment: sorry can't help you any more, all the best

Comment: :)  please help, could you please enhance the karate UI tool for this requirement ?

Comment: nope. this is open source. maybe you can convince a friend or someone else to do this for you 