# Karate - UI Automation - Is it possible to grab Css style attributes of web element

Tags: karate

I am trying to access the below attributes of the web element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5o56.png)

Is there any way in karate where I can grab the CSS style attribute of the UI elements, like how we have in selenium getCssValue("font-size")

I have tried the below code

- print attribute('#eg01SubmitId', 'font-size')

but it's giving an empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JS please, Karate does not need all these fancy API-s.

Please refer the documentation for `script()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#script

And then using normal DOM API-s you can do this:

```
* def displayStyle = script('.Popover', "_.style['display']")
```

I referred this article: https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/

EDIT: if you read the last link, you should have realized that if the styles come from a CSS class etc, you should use `getComputedStyle()`

so try this:

```
* print script('.demo-btn', "function(e){ return getComputedStyle(e)['font-size'] }")
```

Comment: I tried the above way but still getting an empty value, my application is an angular application where all styling attributes are part of a CSS class.

Comment: @PankajBhambhani it works for me. so now please figure this out, contribute code to karate or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I tried with other websites as well where the css styles are embedded in a CSS class 
e.g. https://www.orangehrm.com/ > Get a Free Demo button > it doesn't work, 

here is my code - 

* print script('{button}Get a Free Demo', "_.style['font-size']"), 

another way I tried - 

* def element = locate('{button}Get a Free Demo')
* def getCss = function(m) { return getComputedStyle(m) }
* print getCss(element)
   
but no luck, could you please help ?

Comment: @PankajBhambhani no unless you follow the process

Comment: @PankajBhambhani ok I'll save you some time. please see my edit

Comment: The edited part solved my issue, thanks a lot for the quick help, I looked at getComputedStyle but was not using it correctly :)