# Karate UI-Is karate integrated with ngWebDriver?

Tags: javascript, angular, ui-automation, karate

I want to know if Karate framework can use Angular specific locators to support the angular JS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Karate gives you easy ways to run JS against the HTML DOM, which is all you need.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629911/143475

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900081/143475

```
* def filter = function(x){ x.text.contains('Unique Identifier') }
* def list = locateAll('.grand-parent-class', filter)
* list[0].parent.children[4].click()
```

You should be able to easily write a re-usable function that converts an angular-specifc locator to the actual element. Do contribute your findings back so that it helps others.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and sure will share as I learn and implement more..