# How to verify tooltip text using Karate

Tags: automation, tooltip, karate

How to verify tooltip text using Karate?
Upon hovering mouse over the element, tooltip text is displayed. I need to verify the tooltip text.

Comment: totally depends on the html and JS, refer this for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629911/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter!
I have used other approach, hovered over the element. Tooltip became visible then searched for it using text(locator). It did work.