# Karate DSL: Error retrieving computed style dimensions using script function

Tags: css, user-interface, karate

I'm using Karate DSL version 1.4.0 to perform UI testing and I'm running into an issue when trying to retrieve the computed style properties of a button element. Specifically, I'm trying to get the width and height of a button identified by the id #property.

Here's the test that's causing issues:

```
Feature: Retrieve element style properties using Karate DSL

Background:
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true }

Scenario: Find the width and height of a button
Given driver 'https://letcode.in/buttons'
When waitFor('#property')
* def button = locate('#property')
* def width = script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).width", button)
* def height = script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).height", button)
Then print('Width:', width, 'Height:', height)
```

The script should print the width and height of the element, but instead, I get the following error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
01: script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).width", button)
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (script) ...
```

What could be the cause of this error and how can I correctly retrieve the element's size with Karate DSL?

I've tried and retried many possibilities but continue to fail in the same way.

Much Appreciated,

JB

IGNORE THE ABOVE -> WORKING SCRIPT BELOW

Working test script HERE

```
Scenario: Find the height & width of the button

Given driver 'https://letcode.in/buttons'
* def height = script('#property', "function(e){ return getComputedStyle(e)['height']; }")
* def width = script('#property', "function(e){ return getComputedStyle(e)['width']; }")
* print 'The height is: ' + height + ' and the width is: ' + width
```

Comment: can you let me know if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629911/143475

Comment: Thanks so much @PeterThomas
It worked :) 
Please delete/close/reject this issue.

For anyone who stumbles on this see above for my working tests getting css attributes