# Karate UI Automation - How to clear Text from the CK Editor component?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, karate, browser-automation

How to clear all text/content from the CK editor?
I've already tried all methods such as:
value(locator, '') or * clear(locator). Still not working & test cases are getting passed even though the field is not cleared.

Can refer actual example here - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html

Can anyone help me with the other solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* script('.ck-editor__editable', "_.ckeditorInstance.setData('')")
```

Comment: Yes, It is working now without any issue.
Thanks for the quick response.  @Peter Thomas