# How to make a JS Slider work on Karate DSL UI

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, karate

How is it going;

I'm tring to use Karate UI to develop Web automated tests, but having some problem to work with a JS slider:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itTl7.png)

That element work with a click and drag, where each place of the bar change the value to another amount;

I tryed to use '''value(element, "value")''', but when I use a delay to see what happened in the screen, it moved the bar, but the value dont change...so I cant proceed with the test.

Tried to use input as well, but it dont work as I need.

Someone with more experience on Karate could help?

Thanks

Comment: there are some things that are too hard to build generic support for in karate - so the best option is for you to use some JS on the DOM and solve this. please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas I followed ur advice and asked a dev help to make a React native function to interact with the element; then i've encapsulated the function on a Js file to call it on each feature i need:

Comment: @PeterThomas But we are havin some other troubles to use Match on Karate UI with some text on screen, like that one: 

10:48:02.481 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: $, actual: 'R$ 2.093,14', expected: 'R$ 2.093,14', reason: not equal

home.feature:27 - path: $, actual: 'R$ 2.093,14', expected: 'R$ 2.093,14', reason: not equal

The text is exactly the same on the screen, i'm trying to compare it with a data file or a data_table, but it says the text is not equal. If I use contains and compare only with the numbers carachteres it works...Any idea?

Comment: nope. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue