# How to 'Right click' or 'Context click' on an element in Karate UI

Tags: ui-automation, karate, gherkin, right-click

I have a situation where I have to right click on an element in Karate framework. I discovered that there is no direct facility to do so.

Is there any other way of doing that without the help of Keyboard keys?

Comment: try to use JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475 - else this may need enhancements to karate, so please contribute if you can