# Can Karate select all options in a list? - Karate UI

Tags: karate

On UI, I have a option list, but failed to select all once with Karate, it's only able to select one with `id` or `value` by select `select('select[id=XXX]', '{}xxx')`

Comment: you can consider using JS or contribute code to improve karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: Can you please send us the page link so that we can verify this issue and implement features around it if it needs to be implemented?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.