# Karate drag and drop UI challange

Tags: karate

a part of my Karate UI test is to select date range on calendar element. I was trying all possible ways, but unfortunatelly I'm failing with that.
The calendar is pretty the same solution as on this site: https://automationintesting.online/ (you need to select "Book this room" and then the calendar shows up).

This is a scenario I wrote:

```
Scenario: Calendar drag&drop
Given driver 'https://automationintesting.online/'
And click("//button[text()='Book this room']")
And input("//input[@name='firstname']", "John")
And input("//input[@name='lastname']", "Doe")
And input("//input[@name='email']", "john@email.com")
And input("//input[@name='phone']", "00123456789")
And click("//button[text()='Next']")
And mouse().move("//button[text()='04']").down().move("//button[text()='05']").up()
Then click("//button[text()='Book']")
```

I also tried the solution suggested in this thread [Karate UI drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637144/karate-ui-drag-and-drop)
so for example:

```
* script("var myDragEvent = new Event('dragstart'); myDragEvent.dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()")
* waitFor("//button[text()='08']").script("_.dispatchEvent(myDragEvent)")
* script("var myDropEvent = new Event('drop'); myDropEvent.dataTransfer = myDragEvent.dataTransfer")
* script("//button[text()='09']", "_.dispatchEvent(myDropEvent)")
```

but it also didn't work.

Could anybody help me here?

Comment: I pass on this one. I have nothing to add beyond what is in the link you shared. there may be an opportunity to improve drag-and-drop in karate, but it needs some help from the community. my recommendation is focus on more important automation if possible and get an agreement from your project leaders that not-automating this use-case is ok

Answer (score 0):

This below code has worked for me; it works even for the Iframes; you can give it a try.

```
* script("var dragStartEvent = new MouseEvent('dragstart', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window});")
* script("var dropEvent = new MouseEvent('drop', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window});")
* waitFor("//*[@id='panel1a-content']/div/div[1]").script("_.dispatchEvent(dragStartEvent)")
* script("[data-testid='section__column-section__0--column__0']", "_.dispatchEvent(dropEvent)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me. It's a one-liner, as well.

```
Then script("document.querySelector('placeholder droppable class').appendChild(document.querySelector('element to be dropped'))")
```