# handle calendar date picker with time with Karate UI automation using script() method

Tags: user-interface, web, automated-tests, karate

I am trying to automate a web app where we have start date field. When I am using script() method of karate,  able to enter date time field but after click on submit button, It's throwing an error "please enter the required field". It seems like calendar input field is not aware about value is entered and throw required field error.

Could you please help on this.
the date format is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5aHD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLDqE.png)

I am trying to enter the date in calendar input field. When I am trying to enter the value , I can see the value is entered but field is not aware and on clicking submit button,  it's throwing required field error even value is present. It's only happening during ui automation  when value is entered using *script() method.

Normal input method is not working.

Comment: ui automation is hard. see linked answer, else you have to figure this out on your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.