# Karate UI: Automate the creation of a text box to insert value

Tags: karate, ui-automation

Application contains a 'Pen' icon to draw a text box in a document, for inserting values to a Field name and there is no other workaround to insert new values.

I tried the following actions:

- mouse().move('pen' icon's xpath).click() followed by in the next line -> mouse().move(the document's xpath).click().move(x,y).go()
- click('pen' icon's xpath) followed by in the next line -> mouse().move('pen' icon's xpath).move(the document's xpath).click().move(x,y).go()

Please provide guidance to get the expected output ( create a text box).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can only point you to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475 - the rest is up to you. ui automation is hard. sometimes it is ok to convince whoever is asking you to write this test - that it is not worth it