# Karate Software - how to press button where header has specific value (not in direct path)

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I have task when I want to press button with "Delete" caption according to  string (picture attached). There are many these sections in application and I want to press the Delete button according to specific H6 string.

I need to write click action to find the code with H6 value (this time "app111") and click on the button Delete.

I have tried something like this "rightOf('app111').find('button').click() or below('app111').find('button').click()" in many variations but I was not successful.

In some cases (when the tags are in straight path works for me: click('{//*[normalize-space(text()) = \'' + appName + '\']/../../div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[2]}'), but this time H6 and DIV are on the same level. Now the structure is (more on picture attached):

```
H6
DIV
  A
  DIV
    DIV
    A
    DIV
    A
    BUTTON
       SPAN
```

How to write button click according to H6 value (click on next "Delete" button after H6 with specific string)

Thank you for some help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `near()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#near

Else I think you should write a little JS to get hold of the element. For some ideas, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618233/143475

For example, I think once you select `app111` which should be easy, you can get the `div` after it by getting `element.nextSibling`

Then you run `querySelector('.btn-link')` or something similar, and it should work.

Since you have pasted a screen-shot I can't help more, but if you can follow this process - I can take a look: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tips. I am not so skilled in JS, I have tried it using near(), but I suffer with syntax (I have tried some clicks but it did not work) e.g.: near('{h6}app111').find('button').click()   Another way how to click on button should be select a class with "href=/applications/app111/" - then click on button - the link with the href is in row above the button. I have tried this but it does not work:    1) attempt:  * near("//a[@href='/applications/app111/']").find('{}Delete').click()   2) attempt:
     * near("//a[@href='/applications/app111/']").find('button').click()

Comment: This worked for me finally: click('{//*[normalize-space(text()) = \'app111\']/../div/div/button/span[normalize-space(text()) = \'Delete\']/..}')

Comment: @RadimBukovský thanks for the update ! In the long term we hope `karate-robot` will give teams an easier way to do this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot