# ShadowRoot dom elements access issue in Karate UI

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, karate, shadow-dom

I am trying to access ShadowRoot dom tree elements, but the problem I face is I cannot use the Specific html element to call on .ShadowRoot, as that element is dynamic (see below html snippet id="vaadin-text-field-error-0).  So only way I can do is by accessing the class .vaadin-text-field-container which is one level up. Basically, below is the html code snippet where it returns an "error message = 255 characters max" and in my KarateUI test I am trying to assert that error message. So far I tried the below options based on previous forum queries I read, but no luck I could never access the right element that returns the text "255 characters max" to do the assertion:

Try 1:

```
  * def test = script('.vaadin-text-field-container', '_.innerHTML')
  * print "Error Message is" + test
```

**Output :**

```
evaluation (js) failed: script('.vaadin-text-field-container', '_.innerHTML'), js eval failed twice:(function(){ var fun = function(_){ return _.innerHTML }; var e = document.querySelector(".vaadin-text-field-container"); return fun(e) })(), error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"TypeError","description":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null\n    at fun (<anonymous>:1:46)\n    at <anonymous>:1:130\n    at <anonymous>:1:139","objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":3}"}
```

Try 2:

```
  * def test = script('//*[@id="vaadin-text-field-error-0"]', '_.innerHTML')
  * print 'Error Message is :' + test
```

**Output:**

```
evaluation (js) failed: script('//*[@id="vaadin-text-field-error-0"]', '_.innerHTML'), js eval failed twice:(function(){ var fun = function(_){ return _.innerHTML }; var e = document.evaluate("//*[@id="vaadin-text-field-error-0"]", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue; return fun(e) })(), error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"SyntaxError","description":"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list","objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":3}"}
```

Try 3:

```
* match text('#vaadin-text-field-error-0') == '255 characters max'
```

**Output:**

```
evaluation (js) failed: text('#vaadin-text-field-error-0'), js eval failed twice:document.querySelector("#vaadin-text-field-error-0")['textContent'], error: {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"TypeError","description":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null\n    at <anonymous>:1:53","objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":3}"}
```

**HTML code snippet here:**

```
<vaadin-text-field class="standardformfield" id="runsetup" tabindex="0" required has-label has-helper has-value invalid has-error-message>
#shadow-root (open)
<div class="vaadin-text-field-container">

      <label part="label" id="vaadin-text-field-label-0">Run Name</label>

      <div part="input-field" id="vaadin-text-field-input-0">

        <slot name="prefix"></slot>

        <slot name="input">
          <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-label-0 vaadin-text-field-input-0" placeholder="Type here..." required="" aria-describedby="vaadin-text-field-helper-0 vaadin-text-field-error-0" invalid="" aria-invalid="true">
        </slot>

        <div part="clear-button" id="clearButton" role="button" aria-label="Clear" hidden="true"></div>
        <slot name="suffix"></slot>

      </div>

      <div part="helper-text" id="vaadin-text-field-helper-0">
        <slot name="helper">No special characters, 255 characters max</slot>
      </div>

      <div part="error-message" aria-live="assertive" aria-hidden="false" id="vaadin-text-field-error-0">255 characters max</div>

    </div>

</vaadin-text-field>
```

Can someone please look into this & point me what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this answer does not answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61742555/143475

Please follow this process, so that we can work on adding support for this (in a generic way) in the future: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

We really need community help for some of these things, do consider it.

Comment: Thanks @peter for your Input! Both the below options worked for ShadowRoot elements:                                                                                                                  option 1: * script("document.getElementById('runsetup').shadowRoot.getElementById('vaadin-text-field-error-0').innerText") option 2: * script('document.querySelector("#runsetup").shadowRoot.querySelector("#vaadin-text-field-error-0").innerText')