# How can we press down arrow key in Karate followed by pressing Enter key

Tags: ui-automation, karate, webautomation

Scenario:
[image]

I need to enter address 
Press down arrow key
Press Enter Key

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: A lot depends on the JavaScript and how complex the page is. UI testing is hard, and such questions are impossible to answer remotely.

In theory this should work, refer docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#input

```
* input('#someId', ['blah', Key.DOWN, Key.ENTER])
```

Else look at JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66887724/143475

Or it may be some "shadow DOM" complexity (quite likely for Google stuff): https://stackoverflow.com/a/64723635/143475