# Karate UI test automation using class element

Tags: karate

I am doing a POC on Karate UI automation and have run into something.  I am trying to read some text from a ChatBot we've placed on our companies web page and the div only has a class attribute.  I have tried the following:

```
<div class="message bot-message bot-animation">Hi, I am the Assistant</div>

And waitForText('.messageCls','Hi, I am the Assistant')
```

Received the following error because it could not find it.

> \feature:15 - javascript evaluation failed: waitForText('.messageCls','Hi, I am the Assistant'), wait failed for: .messageCls and condition: _.textContent.includes('Hi, I am the Assistant') after 21047 milliseconds

I've tried `And waitForText('body','Hi, I am the Assistant')` which works but that is not optimal.

What am I missing?

Joe

Answer (score 0):

As per your HTML shouldn't it be:

```
And waitForText('.message', 'Hi, I am the Assistant')
```

I'll be happy to investigate this if your provide a sample following this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I did try that as well and it did not work.

Comment: @Joe sorry I'm going to resort to the "it works for me" card. do help us (and the community) fix a potential bug by providing a way to replicate please

Comment: It works with other objects within the main page, just doesn't work when trying to interact with ChatBot on the page.

Comment: @Joe, ha - sounds like some shadow dom complexity :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618233/143475